# can't find axios api end point when deployed on IIS subdirectory

Tags: node.js, reactjs, iis

I'm trying to deploy my node js and react js app on IIS, I managed to make it run but the APIs that I did, when I try to call it on IIS subdirectory its returning me a 404 error. I already point my endpoint to my localhost:8080//. I'm already at my wits end here and can't seem to find a solution on the net. Thank you in advance for the help that you can give me.

This is my endpoint.js (note /Test is my subdirectory)

```
export const ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:8080/Test";
```

This is my index.js

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = ENDPOINT;
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

This is my code for login

```
  const handleLogin = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = {
      sesaid: sesa.current.value,
      country: country.current.value,
      active: active.current.value,
      fname: fname.current.value,
      lname: lname.current.value,
      empid: empId.current.value,
      email: email.current.value,
    };
    axios
      .post("user/login", data)
      .then(res => {
        if (res.data.success) {
          localStorage.setItem("auth", JSON.stringify(res.data.token));
          window.location.href = "/";
        } else {
          console.log("Failed to login. Please reload page");
        }
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };
```

Comment: You have to edit the question and tell us how you deploy your files to IIS. To make `http://localhost:8080/Test` accessible, you need an IIS site with the correct binding at port 8080 and the proper exceptions to allow traffic to `/Test` IIS application if at site level you already use redirection rules. I cannot see the key information above.

Comment: The 404 is a very generic error, you can enable failed request tracing and post the error log here, it will provide the key error and warning, this link provide the method to enable failed request tracing to capture the detailed error: [link](https://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis).